# Are custom web parts allowed in the Office 365 public sharepoint website?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, office365

I know I can add them to my office 365 team site but it seems I can only add 'gadgets' to my public site.. Is this true ? Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you aren't able to create custom gadgets for SharePoint Online AFAIK. Sure, you can create webparts but they aren't visible on public facing office 365 sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Web Part page your public home page, but you need to choose. It's either the gadget style or the Web Part style, not both.

Some more details on my blog:

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2011/07/20/office-365-some-frustration-with-public-websites/